# Preventing notebook cells from being broken across two pages when printing

Tags: notebooks, printing

Sometimes I create a number of plots together, e.g. by `GraphicsGrid[]`.

If it happens that I have to print the notebook, very often the cell is broken, half on one page and the remaining part on the next -- while I'd like *Mathematica* to print it all in the next page if there is not enough space available.

This also happens if I save the notebook as a PDF.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PageBreakWithin.html

Comment: I know this can be found easily in the documentation, but I also know this is an issue many people encounter (as I did). You tend to search for this in the printing menus and not in the frontend options. I suggest we leave this open and have @Corey's answer as an official answer.

Comment: @alessandro If Corey's comment answers your question, please consider accepting the answer, so that this question will be marked as having an accepted answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If [Corey Kelly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7835/corey-kelly) wishes to answer, this can be deleted.]

The way to prevent page breaks within cells can be found in the documentation:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PageBreakWithin.html

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add a new Item PageBreaks to the Mathematica Menu. First make a backup copy of

C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\MenuSetup.tr

Then edit the original file and add the following block of code, e.g. between the blocks of Window and Help:

```
Menu["&PageBreaks", 
{
        Item["ShowPageBreaks ON ", ShowPageBreaks->True,  Scope->NotebookDefault],
        Item["ShowPageBreaks OFF", ShowPageBreaks->False, Scope->NotebookDefault],
    the original fileDelimiter,
        Item["PageBreak Above Cell ", PageBreakAbove->True,      Scope->SelectionCell],
        Item["NO   PageBreak Above ", PageBreakAbove->False,     Scope->SelectionCell],
        Item["AUTO PageBreak Above ", PageBreakAbove->Automatic, Scope->SelectionCell],
    Delimiter,
        Item["PageBreak Below Cell ", PageBreakBelow->True,      Scope->SelectionCell],
        Item["NO   PageBreak Below ", PageBreakBelow->False,     Scope->SelectionCell],
        Item["AUTO PageBreak Below ", PageBreakBelow->Automatic, Scope->SelectionCell],
    Delimiter,
        Item["PageBreak Within Cell", PageBreakWithin->True,     Scope->SelectionCell],
        Item["NO   PageBreak Within", PageBreakWithin->False,    Scope->SelectionCell],
        Item["AUTO PageBreak Within", PageBreakWithin->Automatic,Scope->SelectionCell],
    Delimiter,
        Item["GroupPageBreak Within", GroupPageBreakWithin->True,Scope->SelectionCell],
        Item["NO   GroupPBr. Within", GroupPageBreakWithin->False,Scope->SelectionCell],
        Item["AUTO GroupPBr. Within", GroupPageBreakWithin->Automatic,Scope->SelectionCell],
}],
```

With these additional menu items, you can easily control the placement of page breaks.

[image: PageBreakMenu added through MenuSetup.tr]

Bingo!

Comment: Didn't know it was "so easy" to modify the main menu, nice ... (Also, there is a little bug in your code, "the original fileDelimiter" should be "Delimiter" ; and I "&PageBreaks" -> "PageBreak")

Answer (score 0):

I also had printing problems and have reverted to a very basic method in order to actually get things to print properly. See my question and answers to a similar problem:

[Problem printing what appears in my notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17494/problem-printing-what-appears-in-my-notebook)